# Set notification to specific time

Tags: android, android-notifications

I would like my notification to run at 12:00pm everyday. How do you replace the when value with a time?

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notify = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"Its Time to Eat",when);

Context context = GrubNOWActivity.this;
CharSequence title = "Its Time to Eat";
CharSequence details = "Click Here to Search for Restaurants";
Intent intent = new Intent(context,Search.class);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
notify.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, details, pending);
nm.notify(0,notify);
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use an alarm manager

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ThisApp.this , myService.class);     
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ThisApp.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 24 hours
```

and put the notification inside myService class!

Comment: but how do one set it for a particular time? let's say i want it to be set when it's 10Pm how do i do that?

Comment: how to set it for specific day only for example Monday to Friday and it's time is 12pm?

Answer (score 1):

The `when` parameter is for sorting the notifications in the status bar. You should code your app such that it fires the notification at the desired time.