# Adobe AIR/FlashBuilder 4.6: Create reminder in Android App

Tags: android, air, flash-builder, flash-builder4.5

I am using Flash Builder 4.6 along with Adobe AIR to create an Android App. I am looking to create some sort of reminder/appointment that will display a notification on screen or in the app bar at the specified time. So far I haven't found a way to do this. I thought I might find this functionality in an ANE[Actionscript Native Extension], however I have yet to come across one.

Is this possible? Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 4):

There are open-source Native Extensions available that enable you to send Notifications on Android. [This](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/notification.html) example by Daniel Koestler includes the ane file, as well as an example project and a tutorial.

To send a Notification at a specific time, you'd need a Native Extension for the Android [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). See SO question [Set notification to specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281075/set-notification-to-specific-time) for more details.

I'm not aware of any available native extension for the AlarmManager on [Adobe's Developer pages](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) or github.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that first link before. I found this ANE for Push Notifications, which includes a method, sendLocalNotification, however, I haven't been able to get it to work - https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification

Comment: Great ane collection you linked to. It seems the scheduled notification via sendLocalNotification is for iOS only: https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification/commit/334513dd7561b05b4d4b78d7ef4617280b53dba2

Comment: Thanks! Here's another collection in case you haven't seen these - https://github.com/patrickkulling/Air-Mobile-Extensions

Comment: Thanks. I knew about that one but it's a great link to share. One of the most comprehensive collections I've seen.