# Android: AlarmManager used to call a Service to notify the user

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-notifications

**Edit** Adding this line in my manifest solved my problem (the `Service` is well created).

```
<service android:name=".TimersService" >
```

**Post**

I'm currently trying to implement alarms to notify the user that a countdown has finished. I have a method `createAlarm()` that adds a new Alarm through an `AlarmManager`. This method is currently called inside a Fragment. It looks like this:

```
private final void createAlarm(String name, long milliInFuture) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(),
                TimersService.class);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity()
                .getApplication(), 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                milliInFuture, pendingIntent); 

    }
```

I expect this method to add an Alarm. The Alarm should be called even if the device is in sleep mode. It should be called at time `milliInFuture` (which is `System.currentTimeMillis()`+ some time). When the alarm is up, it should start a Service. The Service is the following. This `Service` should do only one thing: notify the user that the alarm has finished. My `Service` class is as follows:

```
public class TimersService extends Service {

    private NotificationManager mNM;
    private int NOTIFICATION = 3456;


    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        TimersService getService() {
            return TimersService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        showNotification();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

        private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    private void showNotification() {

        final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.clock_alarm);
        builder.setContentTitle("Time is up");
        builder.setContentText("SLIMS");
        builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 200, 100, 200 });
        final Notification notification = builder.build(); 

        mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
        NOTIFICATION += 1;
    }

}
```

When I run my code, my method createAlarm is called. But my Service is never created. I wrote this code based on Alexander's Fragotsis's one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281075/set-notification-to-specific-time). And my `Service` class is inspired from the Android references of the [Service class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29).

Any idea why my `Service` is not being called ? Is there anything I should write in my `Manifest` about the Alarm,Service or Notification ?

Thank you for your help

Ho and I would appreciate any suggestion about my code. If you know an easier way to notify the user after a fixed amount of time, let me know !

Comment: If all you're doing is making a notification, consider using a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Also, is the service declared in the manifest? Do so if you haven't done it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer !  You were right about the manifest. But I still have some issue. I want my Service to finish once my notification is done. Should I add a stopSelf() in the onStartCommand() or could this be an issue ?

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue, but consider using a receiver instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all you're doing is notifying your user one time, a service is not the best approach for this. Services are meant to do work in the background. A notification is not really the type of work suited for a Service - it's too short. Therefore, I suggest you use a BroadcastReceiver instead.

The class should be something like this:

```
public class TimerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private static final int NOTIFICATION = 3456; 

/*since you're always doing a 1-time notification, we can make this final and static, the number
 won't change. If you want it to change, consider using SharedPreferences or similar to keep track 
 of the number. You would have the same issue with a Service since you call stopself() and so,
 you would delete the object every time.*/

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {

    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.clock_alarm);
    builder.setContentTitle("Time is up");
    builder.setContentText("SLIMS");
    builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 200, 100, 200 });
    final Notification notification = builder.build(); 

    mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
  }
```

To call the receiver, you need to change both the Intent to point to the new class and `getService()` needs to be `getBroadcast()`. Therefore this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(),
                TimersService.class);


PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity()
                .getApplication(), 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

needs to be

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(),
                TimerReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity()
                .getApplication(), 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Also, you should be able to safely change `getActivity().getApplication()` into just `getActivity()`

Lastly you need a manifest declaration:

```
<receiver android:name=".TimerReceiver" ></receiver>
```

Comment: Thank you for this good explanation ! It was very helpful but I still have a question. If two Notification are very close temporally, what happens ? If they have the same ID (as now), is the second notification cancelled or is the first one deleted? If the user has time to delete the first one I suppose that both notifications appear.

Comment: Same id = same notification. You could pass of an int extra to the intent you used for the receiver that specifies the Id you want the notification to have if you want to differentiate.