# .setWhen for notification doesn't works correctly android

Tags: android

I am showing a notification based on time time by user , when I start the app it always displays the notification as keeps on repeating even after cancel, which it incorrect

I doesn't display the notifications on time as set on .setWhen

MainActivity.java

```
calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
day=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
month=(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

cLoader=new CursorLoader(this, BirthdayProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, BirthdayProvider.EVENT_DATE+"='"+day+"' and "+BirthdayProvider.EVENT_MONTH+"='"+month+"'", null, null);
c=cLoader.loadInBackground();
c.moveToFirst();
while (c.moveToNext()) {

calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (month-1));
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,19);//set the alarm time
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 06);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
long calMillis=calendar.getTimeInMillis();
int systemTimeID=(int)System.currentTimeMillis();   


Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, systemTimeID, myIntent,0);             
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calMillis, pendingIntent);
```

MyReceiver.java

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "MyReceiver started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);        
        context.startService(service1);
    }
```

MyAlarmService.java

```
public void onCreate() 
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
       super.onCreate();
       calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        date=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month=(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
        year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

          cLoader=new CursorLoader(this, BirthdayProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, BirthdayProvider.EVENT_DATE+"='"+date+"' and "+BirthdayProvider.EVENT_MONTH+"='"+month+"'", null, null);
        c=cLoader.loadInBackground();
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "My service started ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
   {
       super.onStart(intent, startId);

       /*int count=intent.getIntExtra("count", 0);
       nameArray=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("name");
       numberArray=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("number");*/



    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,(month-1) ); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date); 

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 19); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

        count=count+1;





        mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),SearchListActivity.class);        
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


        RemoteViews remoteView=new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.normal_status_bar);
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.title_name, name);


        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
        .setContent(remoteView)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
        .setLargeIcon(bitmapImage)
        .setTicker("Today's Events")
        .setWhen(calendar.getTimeInMillis())
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(name)
        .setVibrate(new long[] {0, 200, 200, 600, 600})
        .setNumber(count)
        .setSound(uri)
        .setLights(Color.BLUE, 1000, 1000)
        .setContentText("[ Event type : "+eventype+" ]\n\n"+"[ Turns : "+turns+" ]");
        Notification notification = builder.build(); 
        mManager.notify(count, notification);


    }

    }
```

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8281502/1777090) if helps.

Comment: I tried this too earlier , but same problem with this --- code updates

Comment: `setWhen` - Is just a `timestamp` to show in `notification` when it occurs. It doesn't mean `notification` need to be show on on the time `set in when`. Post your complete code. Is it a repeat alarm?

Comment: @Libin --- full code updated ... pls help

Comment: It seem  `while (c.moveToNext())` loop have executed multiple times and notification is shown `n loop times`

Comment: It displays the notifications as soon as I open the app and keeps repeating for 2 or 3 times , but not works as per alarm time

Comment: Make sure alarm time is not past. If alarm time is already past, broadcast receiver will be called immediately when alarm set i.e., you open the app in your scenario

Comment: I always set the alarm time after 2 minutes from the current time for testing

Comment: Ok. See my answer, Problem is with the month

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `month value set`. Don't minus it `calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)` will give the correct month index.

```
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,(month) );
```

So when you `minus` its becomes the `previous month`(not the current month as you expect). Month values starts from `0`. That's the reason the alarm is trigger immediately you start the app( since alarm is past)

As said on the comments - `setWhen` is just a timestamp to show in notification when it occurs. It doesn't mean notification need to be show on on the time set in when

Comment: Even if I put Calendar.MAY for current month, then also it doesn't work

Comment: Try removing the `calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);` line. Also if you want to set time for today just `get the calendar Instance` and set only the hour and mins, getInstance() will have the current date information